# How to detect Chrome Data compression for Android/iOS or Opera Max using JavaScript

Tags: android, ios, mobile, compression, opera

I am looking to try and reliably detect if a mobile device is using data compression through a proxy/cloud. This applies to [Chrome Data compression](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression), [Opera Max](http://www.opera.com/mobile/max) or perhaps [Amazon Silk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/introduction.html).

There are possible [ways](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3517349?hl=en) to detect this at the server level with given headers, but i'd like to see if a javascript method or API may be available instead.

If possible, what would be the easier and most reliable way to determine this at the page level?

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Compression Proxy should send a "Via: 1.1 Chrome-Compression-Proxy" header with all outgoing requests.

Comment: I'm a fairly amateur developer but I have a similar need as the OP. Is this header something that I can only detect at the server level? I'd like to detect it within my Javascript and notify users that the site does not operate correctly when using data compression (the pages often call for updated data from the server, which triggers page refreshes every single time new data is shown).

Comment: @addMitt One important proxy detection you can easily exclude is using `window.operamini` as JS won't run past the page load on Opera Mini. Or you can opt out of Chrome Data compression (with its apparent AJAX issues) by sending a `Cache-Control: no-transform` as now specified on the [FAQs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression#faq).

Comment: Thanks for the updated info! Unfortunately within the current framework we're developing for we do not have direct access to the HTTP Headers sent by the web server, and: <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-transform"/> didn't seem to make a difference, but I'll be looking into some way to get at those headers and request no-transform. Thanks again!